# Azure function API just returning 256 records

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-api

I have created Azure Function Api and this API returning random passwords. I am executing loop 4000 times and calling this API but this API just returning 256 random password and remaining as null...

I have executed same API code locally and it is working fine without function API so look like there is some limitation with Azure Functions.

Can someone please suggest if they encounter same issue or how can scale this up to get 4000+ records?

Please suggest...

This is what i have in my API

```
public static class HashPwd
{
    [FunctionName("HashPwd")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = RandomPassword(name); 

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "TempPassword"
            : $"{name}";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }

    private static string RandomPassword(string name)
    {
        int lengthOfPassword = 8;
        string encyPassword = "";
        string valid = "abcdefghijklmnozABCDEFGHIJKLMNOZ1234567890!@#$%&";
        StringBuilder orgPasswordR = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (0 < lengthOfPassword--)
        {
            orgPasswordR.Append(valid[random.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        string orgPassword = orgPasswordR.ToString();
        return orgPassword;

    }
```

Comment: `this API just returning 256 random password and remaining as null` - what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I find limits about Azure Function in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-functions-limits).
[image]

Please check your configurations(e.g. web.config) and set them up to a bigger number.
Hope it helps.